# Compile time checking existence of stdint.h

Tags: c, typedef, uint32, stdint

I'm working with legacy embedded C code which defines the types `uint8_t, uint16_t` and `uint32_t` in a header file using the `typedef` keyword.

For discussion, let us say the file `typedefs.h` contains these definitions.

In my new C source module, I include `stdint.h`.  I also include other header files which include `typedefs.h` somewhere in the hierarchy.  As expected, the compiler complains about multiple defined symbols.

I would like to modify the legacy file `typedefs.h` so that it only declares the `uint*_t` types if either `stdint.h` is not included or better if the `uint*_t` types are not defined.

My understanding is that `#ifndef` cannot be used since `typedef` is not a preprocessor directive.

So how do I tell the compiler to not define the `uint*_t` if they already exist (or if the `stdint.h` is already included)?

*Note:  this would be easy if the C specification defined standard include guard definitions for the header files.*

FWIW, I am using Green Hills compiler, 4.24, for an ARM9 processor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fix the legacy header to always include `stdint.h` to get these types, remove the duplicate definitions, and provide a drop-in file `stdint.h` for broken systems that lack it.

Answer (score 7):

I beleive that the `stdint.h` should also be defining a macro for the limits of the types that it defines. You should be able to test for those using a `#ifdef` and the like.

```
#ifndef UINT32_MAX
  typdef ... uint32_t;
  #define UINT32_MAX ...
  ...
#endif
```

Edit: Originally used UINT32_MIN, but as Jens Gustedt poited out this is the one combination of signed/unsigned and min/max that doesn't occur.

Comment: Hm, `UINT32_MIN` doesn't exist. `UINT32_MAX` or `INT32_MIN`

Comment: @Jens: The two following seem to suggest that such definitions are required 1) http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html 2) http://linux-documentation.com/en/man/man0p/stdint.h.html

Comment: yes, I know, but my point is that it doesn't require a MIN for an unsigned type, doesn't it, since this is always 0, anyhow.

Comment: @Jens: Ahhh, the light downs. Thanks!

Comment: Looking for UINT32_MAX only tells you if limits.h has been included, not stdint.h. Sometimes people include the one without the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a UNIX system, then you should back-up a step and use a configuration package like autoconf(1) or automake(1).  It's designed to handle problems like this.

Comment: This is an embedded system that doesn't use Unix nor Linux, but ThreadX.  Also, it was coded before `stdint.h` became standard.

Comment: @Thomas: You probably run the Green Hills compiler on an OS other than ThreadX, such as Linux or Windows, right? Very few embedded compilers are self-hosting. That said, autoconf/automake sound like overkill for this situation, and they solve a different problem: "how do I make my code compile on multiple platforms whether they have stdint.h or not?", not "how do I make my new code that uses stdint.h stop conflicting with this old code that defines some of the same types?"